# How do I stop an input when i entered a certain word?

Tags: python

I´m doing a small work for college and i need to stop a certain input when u entered a certain word in python?

I tried this but it isn´t working

```
  if (entrance == 'STOP'): 
      break;
```

Comment: What is `entrance`? Show how you initialize it. Also, `'STOP'` is already a string, no need to call `str`.

Comment: What is entrance? How is it being handled? We need a bit more of the code. Is this a CLI-only app?

Comment: What do you mean by "stop the input"? What exactly should happen?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: How is the input handled? Is entrance a variable?

Comment: when you enter the word 'STOP' in the input you can´t enter anything else @KarlKnechtel

Comment: entrance is the input @DYZ

Comment: With "entrance = input()", you can't force the user to stop typing into the "Command-Line-Interface", the most helpful way is to receive all the user input into `entrance` and then process it like `str.split()` with something like `entrance = entrance.split("STOP")[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIrst of all always provide the maximum information you can about your question. Secondly the brackets around the if conditional and the semi column are redundant in python.

For your problem, try using while loops to test the input of the user.
Something like,

```
 while input() != 'STOP':
 # insert code here
```

Comment: I'll try to do it better next time. It worked with while loop, thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help.